# Giving a child div 0 width?

Tags: css

Quick rundown on what I'm trying to achieve;

I'm making a floating(left) side-nav bar with two child elements, the first being a clickable icon which sits in a static position that will set the second child's width from 0 to 100% of the parents width.

I'm trying to figure out why setting the second child's width to 0%/0 achieves nothing, I can only assume I'm missing something really simple here.

Code: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mjqym5c4/)

```
#header{
    float:left;
    position:fixed;
    background:#333;
    min-height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index:1;
    width:80px;}

#toggle-menu{
    background:url(http://i.imgur.com/EQiq0zb.png) no-repeat;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-size:cover;
    margin:15px 15px;}

#nav{width:0%;}
```

Thanks for helping this noobie in advance,

Dodd

Comment: make the nav `display: none` and when hover on the parent, set it to `display: block;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are just missing this :)

```
#nav{width:0%; overflow:hidden;}
```

Answer (score 0):

`#nav {display: none;}` and when hover on the parent, set it to `display: block;`

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mjqym5c4/2/

```css
body,wrapper{min-height:100px;padding:0;margin:0;font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;}
body{background-color:#999;}

#header{
 float:left;
 position:fixed;
 background:#333;
 min-height:100%;
 overflow:hidden;
 z-index:1;
 width:80px;
}

#header:hover{
 width:200px;
}
#header:hover #nav {
  display: block;
}
#nav {
  display: none;
}

#toggle-menu{
 background:url(http://i.imgur.com/EQiq0zb.png) no-repeat;
 width:50px;
 height:50px;
 background-size:cover;
 margin:15px 15px;
}

#nav{width:0%;}
#nav ul{display:inline;list-style:none;}
#nav ul li{text-align:left;padding:0 15px;}
#nav ul li a{text-shadow:0 1px 2pt black;color:#fff;text-decoration:none;text-transform:uppercase;}


#banner{width:960px;margin: 0 auto;min-height:100px;background:#333;}
#content{width:960px;margin:0 auto;min-height:1000px;background:#666;}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
      <div id="toggle-menu"></div>
      <div id="nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Drive</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /header -->
    <div id="banner">
    </div>
    <div id="content">
    </div>
    <!-- /content -->
    <div id="footer">
    </div>
    <!-- /footer -->
  </div>
  <!-- /wrapper -->
</body>
```

And to answer your question, why `width: 0;` did "nothing", is because the text is not made smaller. For that you would use `font-size: 0;`. But the text will still be there.

Comment: I probably should have mentioned I'm aiming for a transition effect but I think I've got the answer now, thanks a lot!